# Render system wallpaper with gaussian blur

Tags: android, wallpaper, renderscript

I'm using the theme `Theme.Wallpaper` in my launcher in order to display the user's wallpaper within my app. Is it possible to add an overlay that will create a gaussian blur effect on the wallpaper? I've tried using `RenderScript` but for some reason, it doesn't process the wallpaper theme.